# Русский язык - неловкий для использования. Как основатели русского языка не предвидели его неловкость?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, местоимения

Например, местоимения второго рода ед.ч. "ты" и "вы". При таком резком контрасте обращений часто возникают неловкие ситуации. По сравнению, например, с английским языком. Использование слова "вы" отдаляет людей, а английское "you" своей нейтральностью не создает таких проблем и может в подходящих ситуациях иметь значение "ты". Да и в общем, я считаю, что общаться по-английски намного легче и удобнее. Зачем было нужно усложнять язык?

Comment: Неловкий — по отношению к языку? Неловок тот, кто не способен пользоваться языком без затруднений; язык ему не даётся, он ему неудобен.

Answer (score 6):

Неловкие ситуации могут возникать лишь от недостаточного знакомства с другим языком. "Контраст обращений" есть и в других языках, например, tu и lei в итальянском или ni (你) и nin (您) в китайском - их носители не жалуются на "неловкости". Наоборот, дифференцированная форма обращения информативна: со стороны можно оценить, в каком отношении по старшинству, степени знакомства или общественному положению находятся собеседники. В близком вам английском эти аспекты приходится обозначать внешними элементами, например, добавлять sir при почтительном обращении; иногда требуется говорить you all (you guys) - для обозначения обращения при помощи того же you к нескольким собеседникам. В русском тоже применяются такие элементы: чтобы отнести обращение "вы" заведомо к одному из нескольких присутствующих, можно сказать "вы лично" и т. п.

**P.S.** "Основателей русского языка" не было: это естественно сложившийся язык, в отличие от эсперанто и языков программирования.

Answer (score 2):

Вы серьезно полагаете, что язык был создан чьей-то субъективной волей? 
Это не так, разве что волей Божией, о чем недвусмысленно говорит Библия. Так что на основной вопрос по сути ответить невозможно, он некорректный.

Что касается частных вопросов, то:
1. Неловкие ситуации возникают по причине незнания или непонимания этикетных правил, а не языковых.
2. Английский отказался от употребления местоимения единственного числа второго лица (thee/thou) сравнительно недавно, не ранее чем 3-4 века назад. В отдельных случаях - при обращении к Богу, например - оно сохранилось и в современном языке. В тот же период, даже позднее, проникло и вежливое "Вы" в русском - из французского. И тоже на первом этапе порождало массу неловкостей.
3. Ничто не мешает Вам общаться на английском как на языке международного общения. Но зачем же вопреки традициям менять родной язык на иностранный в быту и на государственном уровне? Да и мало кто на это согласиться в общем-то.

Остальное - см. у Alex_ander'а